# jQuery Datatables - Showing 1 of X entries all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've hit an issue where jQuery data tables is showing in the info bar at the bottom:

`Showing 1 of X entries`

This happens upon scrolling down and doesn't update the counter. The total number of records are correct, just not the position within the dataset.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/jubq03oL/3/

Seems to also be doing this on the Scroll Y example on their site:

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

Answer (score 2):

It appears you need the [Scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) extension in order for this functionality to work.

Then changing the JavaScript call to DT enables the functionality:

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
    order:    [[0, 'desc']],
    scrollY:  350,
    deferRender: true,
    scroller: true
});
```

See the following JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jubq03oL/6/

Comment: Glad you found a solution. It's a cool idea, but I knew it wasn't a part of the standard DT library. +1

Answer (score 1):

That number isn't suppose to change unless you have multiple pages.

See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jubq03oL/5/) update. I changed the following:

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
    order: [
        [0, 'desc']
    ],
    scrollY: 350,
    pageLength: 10, // Added to show how the numbering works on multiple pages, not scrolling
    paging: true,
    searching: true });
```

Comment: Hmm odd. I've got a website I've used in the past without pageLength or pagination and it works fine. Baring in mind that it doesn't work on their example pages either.

Comment: The info option on datatables has never shown scroll position. It displays "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries". It updates upon table draw, which is commonly done by going to the next page, or filtering the table. [Docs here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.info)

Comment: Yes but I don't wish to use pagination in this instance, just scrolling down. The code above enables pagination, which is off topic.